# Get last whole number in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, integer, text-extraction

I need to isolate the latest occurring integer in a string containing multiple integers.

How can I get `23` instead of `1` for `$lastnum1`?

```
$text = "1 out of 23";
$lastnum1 = $this->getEval(eregi_replace("[^* out of]", '', $text));
```

Comment: FYI, according to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php), `eregi_replace` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Should probably use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you could do:

```
$text = "1 out of 23";
if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $text, $numbers))
    $lastnum = end($numbers[0]);
```

> **Note** that `$numbers[0]` contains array of strings that matched full pattern,
> and `$numbers[1]` contains array of strings enclosed by tags.

Comment: I used your code and it works. Thanks.

Can you explain how the code works?

Comment: The code works by matching all of the grouped integers in your string and puts them into an array. The last element of the array is then used as your answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$text = "1 out of 23";
$ex = explode(' ',$text);
$last = end($ex);
```

and if you whant to be sure that that last is a number

```
if (is_numeric(end($ex))) {
    $last = end($ex);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

```
$text = "1 out of 23";
preg_match('/(\d+)\D*$/', $text, $m);
$lastnum = $m[1];
```

This will match last number from the string even if it is followed by non digit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_match()` if you can't predict the format of the input string, or `sscanf()` if the string format is predictable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oIC7g))

```
$text = "1 out of 23";

echo preg_match('/\d+(?=\D*$)/', $text, $m) ? $m[0] : '';
echo "\n";
echo sscanf($text, '%*d out of %d')[0];

echo "\n--- \n";

$text = "1 out of 23 more";

echo preg_match('/\d+(?=\D*$)/', $text, $m) ? $m[0] : '';
echo "\n";
echo sscanf($text, '%*d out of %d')[0];
```

All techniques on both input strings return `23`.

In regex, `\d` means a digital character and `\D` means a non-digital character.

With `sscanf()`, `%d` captures one or more digital characters and `%*d` matches but does not capture one or more digital characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match` to extract the values into `$matches`:

```
preg_match("/([0-9]+) out of ([0-9]+)/", $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = '1 out of 23';
preg_match('/\d+ out of (\d+)/', $text, $matches);
$lastnum1 = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format will be the same, why not explode the string and convert the last one?

```
<?php
$text = "1 out of 23";
$words = explode(" ",$text);
$lastnum = (int)array_pop($words);
```