# How can I get the last position of letters in a string formed by letters and numbers in php

Tags: php

I am trying to make an automatic counter to get the last id of my database. I keep rows with an alphanumeric id:

AR1, AR2, AR3, TER17, KAKAP126...

it is varchar in database so I cannot make a +1. So I want to detect the end of the chars (letters) and delete them from the id,  add +1 and concat the number to the letters part.

I tried this:

```
$s = $rowAtt['id']; (ie: TUR99)
echo $s;
echo "<br>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($s); $i++){
   $char = $a[$i-1];
   if (is_numeric($char)) {
      echo $char . ' is a number<br>';
   } else {
      echo $char . ' is a letter<br>';
   }
}
```

But It says always "is a letter"...

What can I do for that?

Comment: use $a{$i-1} (curly brackets)

Comment: I don't want the last character, just the last not number of the string

Comment: it's not the last character - replace square brackets with curly ones to get "<c> is a number"

Comment: I see, but it is the same I already have. I think I need to check each char with the first and the last number of letters. But I don't know how to do it

Comment: do you see the full string? e.g. "E is a letter"

Comment: Your question title and content are different then what you are asking for in the comments. Please update the question and title to more clearly present what you actually want.

Comment: in your code you say strlen($s) but you refer as $a[$i - 1]; $a is not a defined var in your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589519/how-do-i-grab-last-number-in-a-string-in-php

Comment: check since you're indexing the variable $a instead of variable $s

Comment: Yes, you were right. Thanks. Now I can make a counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get both the character and the numeric part separately:

```
  $testString="AAAK12";

  $chars = preg_split("/[0-9]+/", $testString);
  $nums = preg_split("/[a-zA-Z]+/", $testString);

  echo "Chars are " . $chars[0] . "\n";
  echo "Nums are " . $nums[1] . "\n";
```

Result:

```
Chars are AAAK
Nums are 12
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you could try.

```
function getLastLetter($str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $str);
    return substr($str, -1);
}

function getLastLetterPosition($str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $str);
    return strlen($str) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Ahh yours is simpler than mine. +1

Comment: I like this. Is it possible to get the possition instead of the last character? this way I'd just have to use substring after that...

Comment: Sure, just grab the length of the new string and subtract 1.

Answer (score 1):

Simple function that will return the last character, what you do with it is up to you:

```
function getLastChar($string)
{
  $newString = strrev($string);
  for($i=0;$i<=strlen($string);$i++)
  {
    if(!is_numeric($newString[$i])) return $newString[$i];
  }
  return false;
}

echo getLastChar('askdjwu12312');
```

result: u

Answer (score 1):

```
list($characters,$digits) = sscanf('%[A-Z]%d', $myString);
$lastCharacter = substr($characters, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use string length as index:**

A string in PHP can also behave as an array of chars. Therefore we can access each one of them via a simple syntax like: `$string[n]`. Everything else is a matter of using the string length as the index to retrieve the last letter.

This can be translated in code as follows:

```
$myString = 'Hello World';
$lastLetter = $myString[strlen($myString)-1];
```

Regards,
M

Answer (score 0):

The [php manual on substr](http://php.net/substr) says just use `substr($foo, -1)`. Did you try that?

Comment: I don't want the last character, just the last not number of the string