# How do I grab last number in a string and add number in PHP

Tags: php

I have number '1 out of 023' i want 023 from string and add plus 1 number in 023 so new number will be 024 and string will be '1 out of 024'

i used following code (stackoverflow)

```
$text = '1 out of 23';
preg_match('/\d+ out of (\d+)/', $text, $matches);
$lastnum1 = $matches[1];

$text = "1 out of 23";
$words = explode(" ",$text);
$lastnum = (int)array_pop($words);
```

Comment: So you want to grab all numbers out of a string and add them together? Am I right with this?

Comment: no i want only last number from string and add 1 number

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I grab last number in a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589519/how-do-i-grab-last-number-in-a-string-in-php)

Comment: it is not duplicate .... i want some modification

Comment: it is a duplicate. You just dont know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

(Here I just use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get all numbers from your string. After this I use [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to get the last number from the string and then I simply use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the old number with the incremented one)

```
<?php

    echo $text = "1 out of 23" . "<br />";
    preg_match_all("!\d+!", $text, $matches);
    $number = end($matches[0]);
    echo $text = str_replace($number, ++$number, $text);

?>
```

Output:

```
1 out of 23
1 out of 24
```

Comment: @qmobilebmc You're welcome! But please be more specific next time! (See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
$result = array_sum(array_filter(explode(" ", $text), 'is_numeric'));
$text = "1 out of $result";
```

Based on comment:

```
$text = '1 out of 23';
$result = array_filter(explode(" ", $text), 'is_numeric');
$text = str_replace($end = end($result), $end+1, $text);
```

Or:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/[0-9]+$/',
            function ($m) { return ($m[0]+1); }, $text);
```

Comment: Too bad nobody knows what you are talking about.

Comment: ok i want i have string  `$text = '1 out of 23';
preg_match('/\d+ out of (\d+)/', $text, $matches);
$lastnum1 = $matches[1]+1;`   new number is 24 now  i want add updated number into my previous string '1 out of 24'

Comment: @qmobilebmc Last attempt to understand what you want: You want to grab the first and the last number in your string, add them together and updated the string with the new number at the end? (Few examples: `2 out of 10` -> `2 out of 12`; or `1 out of 30` -> `1 out of 31` ?)

Comment: @ Rizier123                                                           i want last number from string  '1 out of 23 '  last string is 23 .....added +1 in 23 now  got 24. at last i want update this number into my string '1 out of 23' (old code) --------------> '1 out of 24' (new updated)

Comment: Not reindexed.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array since it seems like you're looking for the last word and not necessarily the last 3 characters (e.g. what if it were 1 out of 2345).

```
$text = '1 out of 23';
$highest_number = end(explode(" ",$text));

//If you want to to add 1
$highest_number++;

//Or if you want to create a new variable
$new_highest_number = $highest_number + 1;
```