# How Do I Implement Incomplete Answer to Old Question

Tags: php

This comment looks like it would work if the author included the value for $numbers. They say it is some type of array, but don't provide enough information to replicate it. I picture some hard coded array ranging from 0 to 9, but I can't help think that such an array would miss numbers greater than 9. What does the numbers array in this example look like?

```
$text = "1 out of 23";
if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $text, $numbers))
    $lastnum = end($numbers[0]);
```

I would just post a comment asking whoever wrote that to paste the value for $numbers, but it says I need reputation points to do that.

See [How do I grab last number in a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589519/how-do-i-grab-last-number-in-a-string-in-php)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php the 3rd parameter of `preg_match_all()` is an optional one that contains the matched values. The function _returns_ the the number of matches (or false, on failure), so this parameter allows you to also get the matched values themselves in the same function call.

Comment: I am not looking for a boolean output. I am trying to match the numbers so that I can replace them later. This is for a plugin based on Republish Old Posts which I am modifying to change URLs whenever a post is recycled. I want to extract the last number from the string and increase it by 1 or append -1 if there are no numbers. This will result in an integer than can be increased by 1 every time a post is recycled. This is necessary to thwart search engine censorship by tricking them into re-indexing the same stuff at different URLs.

Comment: `preg_match_all()` returns either the # of matches or a boolean. But if you're looking for the matched numbers themselves, those are returned via the `$numbers` parameter. It's not a traditional parameter, and it doesn't need to be defined when passing it to the function. But after the function call, this variable will have the values of the matches. That being said, it sounds like what you're trying to do might be easier using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php because you want to rebuild the string with incremented values.

Comment: In [the documentation for `preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), the 3rd parameter is listed as `&$matches = null`. The `&` there tells you this parameter is passed by _reference_, not value, so the `preg_match_all` function can change the value of the variable without having to _return_ the updated value. This is different than the `$subject` parameter (passed by _value_, without `&` in the function definition) where in your example, any changes to `$text` won't result in a different `$text` value after the function finishes execution.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your initial question `print_r()` can be used to output all contents of an array. e.g. `print_r($numbers)`

https://3v4l.org/2jA1b

To explain the code:

`\d` is a single number
`+` is a quantifier meaning one or more of the previous character or group

so this would find all numbers in a string. The `$numbers[0]` would be all numbers, 1 per index, and the `end()` pulls to the last number/index. Each index would be a number, the `0` is all matches, each indice at the root level is a capture group.

This code wouldn't work as intended for decimals or comma delimited integers. In those cases the numbers would be split up at the delimiter. `1.0` would become `1` and `0` (2 different numbers).

You could rewrite this as:

```
$text = "1 out of 23";
if(preg_match('/.*\K\D\d+/', $text, $numbers))
    echo $numbers[0];
```

so the `end` function is not needed. This pulls everything until the last number then forgets everything before the last number.

Comment: Interesting, I can't use print for this because the code doesn't set the value of the $numbers variable. My question is what does $numbers look like. right now a print of that would not produce anything.

Comment: Why would `print_r` produce nothing? You could do `implode(PHP_EOL, $numbers[0])` and echo that or `error_log` it. Click the first link and you can see the array, https://3v4l.org/2jA1b.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is likely easier using [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of `preg_match_all`. We can split the input text by the matched regex (digits) and then rebuild the string while incrementing the numbers as we go.

```
<?php

function incrementNumbers($text) {
    // NOTES:
    // parenthesis are important in the regex in order to return the captured values
    // the -? will capture negative numbers too if necessary
    // PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE allows the captured values to be returned too
    $split = preg_split('/(-?\d+)/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    
    $return = '';
    foreach($split as $i => $s) {
        // because we didn't use PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY, $split[0] will either be an empty string if
        // $text began with a number, or the text before the first number. Either way, $split alternates
        // between non-number [0], number [1], non-number [2], number [3], etc which is why we can detect
        // even or odd indexes to determine if this is a number that needs to be incremented or not
        if ($i % 2 === 0) {
            $return .= $s;
        } else {
            $return .= (intval($s) + 1);    
        }
        
    }
    
    return $return;
}
```

Examples:

```
echo incrementNumbers("1 out of 23 with 1 and 1 and 24 and 23");
echo incrementNumbers("1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 1");
echo incrementNumbers("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
echo incrementNumbers("-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
echo incrementNumbers("there are no numbers in this text");
echo incrementNumbers("does not start 999 with a number 123 nor end 17 with a number");
```

Outputs:

```
2 out of 24 with 2 and 2 and 25 and 24
2 2 3 3 4 4 3 3 2 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
there are no numbers in this text
does not start 1000 with a number 124 nor end 18 with a number
```

Working example at https://3v4l.org/iKskO